# How to split my string with a delimiter but escape delimiter in data?

Tags: python, regex

This is my input data sample

```
data = "1000616411022604|1000616410908275|10.00|ktefwrj\"w\\|2014-02-25|debit|\|tcsceldxz"
```

I want the parsed output to look like this

```
["1000616411022604", "1000616410908275" , "10.00", "ktefwrj\"w\\", "2014-02-25", "debit", "\|tcsceldxz"]
```

but my output is looking like this

```
['1000616411022604', '1000616410908275', '10.00', 'ktefwrj"w\\', '2014-02-25', 'debit', '\\', 'tcsceldxz']
```

By looking at some of the code in stackoverflow I tried to use re but it's not working

```
data = re.split(r'[^\\]|', data)
```

I am trying to do this in python using regular expression. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should give this page a review first: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

where you can see that what you are trying to keep are escape sequences that by default and especially python 3 automatically formats when manipulating the text.

If you still want to have a result very similar to what you show us as output you can try this:

```
import string
data = '1000616411022604|1000616410908275|10.00|ktefwrj\"w\\|2014-02-25|debit|\|tcsceldxz'

def _parse(val):
    return r'{}'.format(val.replace('"', '\\"').replace("'", "\\'"))

_split_test = re.split(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_])\||\|(?=[0-9-])', str(_parse(data))) 
print(_split_test)
```

output:

```
['1000616411022604', '1000616410908275', '10.00', 'ktefwrj\\"w\\', '2014-02-25', 'debit', '\\|tcsceldxz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to keep the escape characters as well?

if so make data = r'string'

when you print, the extra escape characters condense down to give you what I think you want.

I used data.split('|') for the list generation

The | causes a bit of a bind, so you've tried something like:

```
re.split(r'(?<!\\)\|',data)
```

This also causes issues because it then misses \| for an earlier split.

How prevalent are these | that you want to keep in the last column?

you could just do the split on '|' and then do a join on the last two columns to put one '|' back or conditionally if split generates a list of the inappropriate length.

also keep in mind that it's pretty obvious some columns contain dates and certain types of data, so you can use this to do some sanity checks if your splits throw you through a loop.

Comment: I did not understand your answer. I want to split the string on the delimiter "|" but the delimiter is also present in some of the column data with an escape char. Splitting it by "|" will create more columns than I intend to. @Clinton Bradfield